# Preciso acessar índices de uma array java

Tags: java

```
public class Conteudo {   
public List<String> Matriz(String[] array){

    String CaminhoArquivo=("C:\\Users\\jessica borges"
            + "\\Downloads\\CalculadoraMatrizes-20190315T112959Z-001"
            + "\\CalculadoraMatrizes-20190315T112959Z-001"
            + "\\CalculadoraMatrizes\\src\\ArquivosMatriz\\matrix.txt");

    List<String> conteudo = new ArrayList<>(); 
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CaminhoArquivo));
            String linha;
            while ((linha = in.readLine()) != null) { 
               int var[] = new int[conteudo.size()];
                conteudo.addAll(Arrays.asList(linha.split(" ")));   
        }   
         in.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
        System.out.println(conteudo);
        return conteudo;
```

}

```
public void conteudo(String[] array){

}
```

}

Preciso acessar os índices dessa array conteudo para tratar em outro método.

Comment: `public List<String> Matriz()` << esse método quero pegar o que ele retorna e tratar nesse outro método `public void Matriz22()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No momento que você adicionou os elementos na lista, você pode acessar assim:

```
conteudo.get(i) //Onde i é o índice.
```

E caso seja um array "String[]", então acessa:

```
String[] array = new String[10];
System.out.println(array[i]) //Onde i é o índice;
```

Referência [aqui](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-get-method-example/)

Comment: Porém eu preciso tratar esses índices em outro método, nesse método eu apenas saldo o conteúdo que vem de um arquivo txt salvo em uma array "conteúdo".